# Why won't my swift code process firebase email authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have view controllers connected with my code that include a login page and a sign up page, I've started a firebase project and connected with my Xcode and it successfully connected to the firebase servers. The code below is for my sign up view controller and is supposed to act like a sign up form with email, password and password confirmation but for some reason the build succeeds with no errors but the user that registered does not show up on my firebase user database and the textfields don't act like the way they should (i.e throw an error if password and password confirmation don't match) .

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase


class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
  @IBAction func SignUpToHome(sender: AnyObject) {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUpToHome", sender: sender)
     }
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //}
        if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
    else{
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in
     if error == nil {
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUpToHome", sender: self)
                    }
     else{
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
       let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                        
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }
                }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't signing in after creating an account.

Comment: @ElTomato ah that worked, how silly of me. Thanks :)